# How do I stop Keras showing "using XXX backend"?

Tags: python, keras

"Using XXX backend" would print when I import keras.

```
import keras
```

Outputs:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

But I clearly know what I am using.

How to disable it?

Comment: which version of tensorflow, keras,dask are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow 1.8.0, keras 2.1.6, dask 0.18.1.

Answer (score 9):

Just using the code below.

```
import os
import sys
stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
import keras
sys.stderr = stderr
```

Answer (score 4):

workaround for this problem:

```
stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
import keras
sys.stderr = stderr
```

You can find more info in keras issues [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1406)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Tensorflow 2.0`, then you might get an error saying `AttributeError: module 'tf' has no attribute 'logging'`

Unfortunately `tf.logging` has been removed from `tensorflow 2.0`. Please execute the below commands:

`import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
First comment in here `keras/backend/__init__.py` the string `print('Using TensorFlow backend.')`, but of course this option is not suggested since you are going to edit code in the keras module.
The second option is:

```
import sys
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('/dev/null', 'w')
import keras
sys.stdout = stdout
```

It's not elegant, but it works.

Comment: I found this needed to be using stderr, as in other answers, not stdout

Comment: stderr should be used not stdout .. otherwise all outputs will be redirected to null

Answer (score 0):

First comment in here "keras/backend/**init**.py" the string print('Using TensorFlow backend.') it will work!!.. but it is not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to hide keras printing "using Tensorflow backend"

Suggested here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1406

```
import ...

import os
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
with redirect_stderr(open(os.devnull, "w")):
    import keras

import ...
import ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Include this line in your code. It will ignore the error.

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is what happens. AttributeError: module 'tf' has no attribute 'logging'

Comment: @RKO Unfortunately `tf.logging` has been removed from `tensorflow 2.0`. Please execute the below commands:

`import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()  
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)  
`

Comment: The 'Using XXX backend' is not logged from Tensorflow but from Keras, so updating TF log levels won't help.