# Hide Using TensorFlow backend. message in TensorFlow 2.0 Alpha

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Importing TensorFlow 2.0 Alpha the following message is printed:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

How can this message be hidden, so it will not print out?

The operating system is Windows, and I tried the following:

```
import os
import sys
stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
import tensorflow as tf
sys.stderr = stderr
```

which does not eliminate the message.

The TensorFlow version is

```
print(tf.__version__)
2.0.0-alpha0
```

This print out seems to emanate from Keras:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1406

[Keras disable showing using XXX backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456842/keras-disable-showing-using-xxx-backend)

Answer (score 0):

I have a linux system so I'm not sure if this will work for you, but the following code suppresses the message for me:

```
import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

You should only see print outs of error messages.
(from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26662)